# i have this error : error TS2339: Property does not exist on type

Tags: angular

I have this error :
 error TS2339: Property 'getConfig' does not exist on type 'ConfigComponent'
this is my file config.component.ts :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { ConfigService } from '../config.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-config',
  templateUrl: './config.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./config.component.css']
})

export class ConfigComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private configService : ConfigService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getConfig();
  }

  showConfig() {
    this.configService.getConfig()
      .subscribe((data: any) => this.config = {
          heroesUrl: data['heroesUrl'],
          textfile:  data['textfile']
      });
  }
}
```

this my file config.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ConfigService {
  configUrl = 'assets/config.json';
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getConfig() {
    return this.http.get(this.configUrl);
  }

}
```

And this is my file config.json

```
{
  "heroesUrl": "http://localhost:3000/Entrees",
  "textfile": "assets/textfile.txt"
}
```

I don't understand why I have this error. In CMD I have this error :

> ERROR in src/app/config/config.component.ts(16,10): error TS2339:
>   Property 'getConfig' does not exist on type 'ConfigComponent'.
>       src/app/config/config.component.ts(21,38): error TS2339: Property 'config' does not exist on type 'ConfigComponent'.

Comment: `getConfig` method is available in your service not in the component. Also there is no property `config` in your component. Get the basic understanding from https://angular.io/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the **`ConfigComponent`** you should change your method to **`showConfig`**,

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.showConfig();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It think you missed declaring the `config` variable on the class and the call `showConfig` instead of `getConfig` in `ConfigComponent`

```
constructor(private configService : ConfigService, private config: <Config>) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.showConfig();
}
```